# The most efficient way to loop n-d np.array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

#### 1. Introduction

Assuming there is a 3-d array in the shape of (365,100,100): *Prec*.

- It represent the daily precipitation condition of an area for whole year.
- Apparently, the first dimension represent the time series.
- The last 2 dimensions represent the spatial distribution(for example, there are 10000 grids in size 1km x 1 km)

#### 2. Attempt

Test each grid for whole area whether its precipitation above certain value Pd which separate dry and wet. I want to sum the dry day for the whole year.

#### 3. My code

```
freq = np.zeros(100,100).reshape(100,100)
Pd = xxx
for i in range(0,prec.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0,prec.shape[1],1):
        for k in range(0,prec.shape[2],1):   
            if prec[i,j,k] < Pd:
               freq[j,k] +=1
```

I think too many loop must waste time. Are there some cleanest way to achieve similar work?
Any advices would be  appreciate!

Comment: Divakar's answer below is excellent. Personally, I think that for this type of stuff, `numpy` is too low level, and `pandas` is the way to go.

Comment: I'm only familiar with dataframe with `pandas`. I'll try n-d array in `pandas` some day! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing and summing along the first axis of `prec`. That comparison could be performed using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in a vectorized manner and then sum along the first axis with [`.sum(0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), like so -

```
freq = (prec < Pd).sum(0)
```

Comment: No loops - very elegant.

Comment: May I ask what the principle of these kind of code? I have met with some similar code like `array[array > 0.5]`. The  efficiency are so greater than loop. Why they are so fast? Don't they need loop to  traverse all the value ?

Comment: @HanZhengzu [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8385658/3293881) might shed some light. NumPy is built for performing the same operation on a huge number of elements in a vectorized fast way. I think the philosophy with it is [`SIMD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD).