# Finding the min or max sum of a row in an array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I quickly find the min or max sum of the elements of a row in an array?

For example:

```
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
7, 8
```

The minimum sum would be row 0 (1 + 2), and the maximum sum would be row 3 (7 + 8)

```
  print mat.shape
  (8, 1, 2)  
  print mat
 [[[-995.40045 -409.15112]]

 [[-989.1511  3365.3267 ]]

 [[-989.1511  3365.3267 ]]

 [[1674.5447  3035.3523 ]]

 [[   0.         0.     ]]

 [[   0.      3199.     ]]

 [[   0.      3199.     ]]

 [[2367.      3199.     ]]]
```

Comment: How is your array formatted, and have you tried anything that fails?

Comment: It is a tuple of 1 by 2 numpy array. I do for-loop and compare the values to find the min and max pair. I think there is a better and more "pythonic" way..

Comment: Sorry, could you just post the exact array, as formatted in numpy?

Comment: Why not a 4x2 NumPy array?

Answer (score 7):

In native Python, `min` and `max` have key functions:

```
>>> LoT=[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
>>> min(LoT, key=sum)
(1, 2)
>>> max(LoT, key=sum)
(7, 8)
```

If you want the *index* of the first min or max in Python, you would do something like:

```
>>> min(((i, t) for i, t in enumerate(LoT)), key=lambda (i,x): sum(x))
(0, (1, 2))
```

And then peel that tuple apart to get what you want. You also could use that in numpy, but at unknown (to me) performance cost.

---

In numpy, you can do:

```
>>> a=np.array(LoT)
>>> a[a.sum(axis=1).argmin()]
array([1, 2])
>>> a[a.sum(axis=1).argmax()]
array([7, 8])
```

To get the index only:

```
>>> a.sum(axis=1).argmax()
3
```

Comment: The Numpy way is generally more performant. Explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385658/5398884

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `np.argmin` and `np.sum`:

```
array_minimum_index = np.argmin([np.sum(x, axis=1) for x in mat])
array_maximum_index = np.argmax([np.sum(x, axis=1) for x in mat])
```

For your array, this results in `array_minimum_index = 0` and `array_maximum_index = 7`, as your sums at those indices are `-1404.55157` and `5566.0`

To simply print out the values of the min and max sum, you can do this:

```
array_sum_min = min([np.sum(x,axis=1) for x in mat])
array_sum_max = max([np.sum(x,axis=1) for x in mat])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = np.sum(x,axis=1)
min_x = x.min()
max_x = x.max()
```

presuming x is 4,2 array use np.sum to sum across the rows, then .min() returns the min value of your array and .max() returns the max value

Comment: Can you explain your code rather than doing a code dump? Thanks!

Comment: presuming x is 4,2 array use sum to sum across the rows, then .min() returns the min value of your array and .max() returns the max value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` and `max` and use `sum` as their key.

```
lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]

min(lst, key=sum) # (1, 2)
max(lst, key=sum) # (7, 8)
```

If you want the sum directly and you do not care about the tuple itself, then `map` can be of help.

```
min(map(sum, lst)) # 3
max(map(sum, lst)) # 15
```