# dev_appserver.py app.yaml produces: ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed

Tags: python, numpy, google-app-engine

I run this command:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

and I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\Desktop\ToolKit\Application Projects\Tableau Web Data Connector Improvement\tableauextensions\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Get_Data import get_data, build_connection, run_sql
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\Desktop\ToolKit\Application Projects\Tableau Web Data Connector Improvement\tableauextensions\Get_Data.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\Desktop\ToolKit\Application Projects\Tableau Web Data Connector Improvement\tableauextensions\lib\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\Desktop\ToolKit\Application Projects\Tableau Web Data Connector Improvement\tableauextensions\lib\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\Desktop\ToolKit\Application Projects\Tableau Web Data Connector Improvement\tableauextensions\lib\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\Desktop\ToolKit\Application Projects\Tableau Web Data Connector Improvement\tableauextensions\lib\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\sehrlich\Desktop\ToolKit\Application Projects\Tableau Web Data Connector Improvement\tableauextensions\lib\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

I have installed and uninstalled NumPy.  They app works fine when I run something like

```
python -m flask run
```

and it uses NumPy no problem. Can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Are you [requesting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime) the GAE provided `numpy` or trying to [vendor in](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) your own version as the file paths in your tracebacks appear to suggest? (I suspect it's not pure python code, if so it can't be vendored in).

Comment: Hi There @danCornilescu, I am requesting GAE provided numpy.  That link is exactly what I was looking for.  What is best solution for enabling numpy to be used in my Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

As Dan Cornilescu said, GAE Standard can't use libraries with code compiled in C [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#standard_environment_languages_and_runtimes):

> *[From 1]* You can use third-party libraries that are pure Python code with no C extensions
>
> *[From 2]* The interpreter cannot load Python services with C code; it is a "pure" Python environment.

NumPy is one of those cases, you can see it in their Git Repo [[3]](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/core/src) and in Wikipedia [[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) (Written in: Python, C). Also, check the first answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385602/why-are-numpy-arrays-so-fast).

Curiously enough, I found a version on NumPy only based on "pure" Python called "TinyNumPy" [[5]](https://github.com/wadetb/tinynumpy) that you could use in GAE Standard. This are its limitations according to their Git Repo:

> - ndarray.flat iterator cannot be indexed (it is a generator).
> - No support for Fortran order.
> - Support for data types limited to bool, uin8, uint16, uint32, uint64, int8, int16, int32, int64, float32, float64.
> - Functions that calculate statistics on the data are much slower, since the iteration takes place in Python.
> - Assigning via slicing is usually pretty fast, but can be slow if the striding is unfortunate.

In a nutshell, either you use GAE Flex or try to avoid NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use the GAE-supplied `numpy` then:

- you shouldn't have it installed inside your application code (the traceback indicates it's running from the app's `lib` dir, where vendored-in libraries go)
- you should request it in your `app.yaml`'s `libraries` section:

  ```
  libraries:
  - name: numpy
    version: "1.6.1"
  ```
- you should also have the requested `numpy` version installed locally on your system (but not in the app dir) so that the development server can use it as `numpy` is one of the libraries with such requirement, see [Using built-in bundled libraries with the local development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#local_development):

> Many of the built-in libraries provided by the runtime are
>   automatically available to the local development server. However, the
>   following built-in libraries must be installed locally before you can
>   use them with the local development server:
>
> ...
>
> - [numpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy)

Comment: Great Response!  This does answer the question correctly!  As a side note though, why does google only have this version of Numpy.  My application needs to use version 1.9 or later but looks like they do not support it.

Comment: My guess is that it's not exactly trivial to port these packages/versions to make them work decently on GAE, with the sandbox/infra restrictions. So it becomes a matter of resources, priorities, etc.