# Fastest way to find all the indexes of maximum value in a list - Python

Tags: python-3.x, collections, python-itertools

I am having list which as follows

```
input_list= [2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5]
```

I want to get all the indexes of maximum value. Need efficient solution. The output will be as follows.

```
output = [2,4,6] (The above list 5 is maximum value in a list)
```

I have tried by using below code

```
m = max(input_list)
output = [i for i, j in enumerate(a) if j == m]
```

I need to find any other optimum solution.

Comment: You are doing two pass, the best you can do it in single pass, keeping track of current maximum and its all indexes , but again time complexity for the algorithm would still be `O(<size_of_input_list>)` or `O(len(input_list))`.

Comment: Given that (in CPython) `max` loops in C and that your list comprehension allocates very little extra memory, what you have may already be optimal (rather than merely asymptotically optimal).

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop for `O(n)` and iterating just once over the list resolution:

```
from itertools import islice

input_list= [2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5]

def max_indexes(l):
    max_item = input_list[0]
    indexes = [0]
    for i, item in enumerate(islice(l, 1, None), 1):
        if item < max_item:
            continue
        elif item > max_item:
            max_item = item
            indexes = [i]
        elif item == max_item:
            indexes.append(i)
    return indexes
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/InsidiousStrangeVirtualmemory)

Comment: Not sure if this is different then what the OP already does, but seems to add more verbosity to the solution!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, It is verbose in purpose to explain all the conditions. And it is the only answer that solves it in one iteration over the elements :)

Comment: So the complexity does get reduced from 2 to 1 iterations, but still the time complexity is O(n),  maybe you want to mention that in your comment ?

Comment: is it fine if I take your idea of doing in it one iteration, but implement in another way?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, yeah, your answer LGTM :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 dic=defaultdict(list)
 input_list=[]
 for i in range(len(input_list)):
         dic[input_list[i]]+=[i]

 max_value = max(input_list)

 Sol = dic[max_value]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach which is described in comments. Even if you use some library, fundamentally you need to traverse at least once to solve this problem `(considering input list is unsorted)`. So even lower bound for the algorithm would be Omega(size_of_list). If list is sorted we can leverage `binary_search` to solve the problem.

```
def max_indexes(l): 
     try: 
         assert l != [] 
         max_element = l[0] 
         indexes = [0] 
         for index, element in enumerate(l[1:]): 
             if element > max_element: 
                 max_element = element 
                 indexes = [index + 1] 
             elif element == max_element: 
                 indexes.append(index + 1) 
         return indexes 
     except AssertionError: 
         print ('input_list in empty')
```

Comment: That try/except block is completely unnecessary. Also this answer is just a slightly modified version of one ot the other answers and do not make any improvement whatsoever.

Comment: @Netwave we may need to check whether it is an empty list or not, it is just a way to perform defensive programming.

Comment: That message is just a sample of how OP wants to handle that error.

Comment: Why not using IndexError instead? or check if the list is empty and actually raise and exception?

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in this way, unless you iterate through the whole list once, which is `O(n)`, n being the length of the list, you won't be able to compare the maximum with all values in the list, so the best you can do is `O(n)`, which you already seems to be doing in your example.

So I am not sure you can do it faster than `O(n)` with the list approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `numpy` (`numpy` arrays are very [fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385602/why-are-numpy-arrays-so-fast)):

```
import numpy as np
input_list= np.array([2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5])
i, = np.where(input_list == np.max(input_list))
print(i)
```

Output:

```
[2 4 6]
```