# Fast loop algorithm open cv python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

i created an algorithm with two for-loops for my gray image.
Every pixel above the value 180 and on the left side of the image gets a new value.

This algorithm is very slow and takes a few seconds.

Is there a faster way to do this job?

```
   for x in range(img.shape[0]):
        for y in range(img.shape[1]):
            if(img[x,y]>180 or y>450):
                img[x,y]=255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should employ vectorized `numpy` operations, something like

```py
img[img > 180] = 255
img[:,450:] = 255
```

Should do exactly what your loop does, but [much more quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8385602/10659910). To apply both conditions together you can do

```py
img[:,450:][img[:,450:] > 180] = 255
```

Comment: I found a mistake in my code. It should be 'and' instead of 'or'. Is it possible to use these operators in an and-condition?

Comment: @EdwinB. See the edit, and if this answers your question don't neglect to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so the question is marked as such for future users.

Comment: I don't know why, but the code is not working. Is there maybe a problem with the brackets?

Comment: @EdwinB. My apologies, I have fixed it - should work now.

Comment: Thanks, now its working, but somehow it changes only the pixels on the right side of the image. But the solution should be simple

Comment: @EdwinB. If you want to apply to the left size instead simply change `img[:,450:]` to `img[:,:450]`