# Any easy way to transform a missing number sequence to its range?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list that goes like :
'''
[1,2,3,4,9,10,11,20]
'''
I need the result to be like :
'''
[[4,9],[11,20]]
'''
I have defined a function that goes like this :

```
def get_range(lst):
i=0
seqrange=[]
for new in lst:
    a=[]
    start=new
    end=new
    if i==0:
        i=1
        old=new
    else:
        if new - old >1:
            a.append(old)
            a.append(new)
    old=new
    if len(a):
        seqrange.append(a)
return seqrange
```

Is there any other easier and efficient way to do it? I need to do this in the range of millions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy arrays and the [`diff` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) that comes along with them. Numpy is *so much more efficient* than looping when you have millions of rows.

---

Slight aside:
[Why are numpy arrays so fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8385602/843953) Because they are *arrays of data* instead of arrays of pointers to data (which is what Python lists are), because they offload a whole bunch of computations to a backend written in C, and because they leverage the SIMD paradigm to run a **S**ingle **I**nstruction on **M**ultiple **D**ata simultaneously.

---

Now back to the problem at hand:

The `diff` function gives us the difference between consecutive elements of the array. Pretty convenient, given that we need to find where this difference is greater than a known `threshold`!

```
import numpy as np

threshold = 1
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,9,10,11,20])

deltas = np.diff(arr)
# There's a gap wherever the delta is greater than our threshold
gaps = deltas > threshold 
gap_indices = np.argwhere(gaps)

gap_starts = arr[gap_indices]
gap_ends = arr[gap_indices + 1] 

# Finally, stack the two arrays horizontally
all_gaps = np.hstack((gap_starts, gap_ends))
print(all_gaps)
# Output: 
# [[ 4  9]
#  [11 20]]
```

You can access `all_gaps` like a 2D matrix: `all_gaps[0, 1]` would give you `9`, for example. If you really need the answer as a list-of-lists, simply convert it like so:

```
all_gaps_list = all_gaps.tolist()
print(all_gaps_list)
# Output: [[4, 9], [11, 20]]
```

---

Comparing the runtime of the iterative method from [@happydave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247681/843953) with the numpy method:

```
import random
import timeit

import numpy

def gaps1(arr, threshold):
    deltas = np.diff(arr)
    gaps = deltas > threshold 
    gap_indices = np.argwhere(gaps)
    gap_starts = arr[gap_indices]
    gap_ends = arr[gap_indices + 1] 
    all_gaps = np.hstack((gap_starts, gap_ends))
    return all_gaps

def gaps2(lst, thr):
    seqrange = []
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
      if lst[i+1] - lst[i] > thr:
        seqrange.append([lst[i], lst[i+1]])
    return seqrange

test_list = [i for i in range(100000)]
for i in range(100):
    test_list.remove(random.randint(0, len(test_list) - 1))

test_arr = np.array(test_list)

# Make sure both give the same answer:
assert np.all(gaps1(test_arr, 1) == gaps2(test_list, 1))

t1 = timeit.timeit('gaps1(test_arr, 1)', setup='from __main__ import gaps1, test_arr', number=100)
t2 = timeit.timeit('gaps2(test_list, 1)', setup='from __main__ import gaps2, test_list', number=100)

print(f"t1 = {t1}s; t2 = {t2}s; Numpy gives ~{t2 // t1}x speedup")
```

On my laptop, this gives:

```
t1 = 0.020834800001466647s; t2 = 1.2446780000027502s; Numpy gives ~59.0x speedup
```

My word that's fast!

Answer (score 1):

There is iterator based solution. It'is allow to get intervals one by one:

```
flist =  [1,2,3,4,9,10,11,20]


def get_range(lst):
    start_idx = lst[0]
    for current_idx in flist[1:]:
        if current_idx > start_idx+1:
            yield [start_idx, current_idx]
        start_idx = current_idx


for inverval in get_range(flist):
    print(inverval)
```

Comment: молодец Stanislav

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything inefficient about the solution, but you can clean up the code quite a bit:

```
seqrange = []
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
  if lst[i+1] - lst[i] > 1:
    seqrange.append([lst[i], lst[i+1]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Don't know the feasibility when using millions of numbers though, will update upon testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be more efficient and a bit cleaner.

```
def func(lst):
    ans=0
    final=[]
    sol=[]
    for i in range(1,lst[-1]+1):
        if(i not in lst):
            ans+=1
            final.append(i)
        elif(i in lst and ans>0):
            final=[final[0]-1,i]
            sol.append(final)
            ans=0
            final=[]
        else:
            final=[]
    return(sol)
```