# python massive performance difference array iteration vs "if in"

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, for-in-loop

Both the code snippets below check if an element exists in the array but first approach takes < 100ms while the second approach takes ~6 seconds .

Does anyone know why ?

````
import numpy as np
import time

xs = np.random.randint(90000000, size=8000000)

start = time.monotonic()
is_present = -4 in xs

end = time.monotonic()

print( 'exec time:', round(end-start, 3) , 'sec ') // 100 milliseconds

start = time.monotonic()
for x in xs:
  if (x == -4):
    break

end = time.monotonic()

print( 'exec time:', round(end-start, 3) , 'sec ') // 6000 milliseconds ```
````

[repl link](https://replit.com/@sahilb1/MurkyCraftyEditors#main.py)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385602/why-are-numpy-arrays-so-fast and https://medium.com/@gough.cory/performance-of-numpy-array-vs-python-list-194c8e283b65

Comment: Try this with PyPy rather than CPython and it is magically much faster and the gap is getting closer. The reason is that CPython is a (slow) *interpreter*. The first line execute a optimized native C call while the second use the interpreter to iterate over the list (which is insanely slow compared to doing that using a native compiled code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy is specifically built to accelerate this kind of code, it is written in c with almost all of the python overhead removed, comparatively your second attempt is pure python so it takes much longer to loop through all the elements