# Generate an equally-sized group of indices in Python

Tags: python, split

I am interested to get an equally-sized group of indices. For example I have the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np

p = 2
n  = 10
labels = np.random.randint(p, size=n)
```

The code above will create `10` labels (`0` and `1` values) but not necessarily that the total number of `0's` is equal to the total number of `1's`. What do I need is to automatically obtain the same number: for example `0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1` (where there are really five `0's` and five `1's`). The same concept of the example above can be generalized for any `p` and `n` such that `n/p` is an integer.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the generic case.

Generate a list, then shuffle it using

```
labels = [int(x/(n/p)) for x in range(0,n)]
np.random.shuffle(labels)
```

Comment: nb, make sure you check n and p are valid first.

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just create a list with the equal number of zeroes and ones and then shuffle it using `np.random.shuffle(arr)`

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html

Comment: And how do you create a list with the equal number of zeros and ones?

Comment: @Christina many ways. [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1] :) or [0]*5 + [1]*5

Comment: There can be many ways one of them can be to use `numpy.ones` and `numpy.zeros` to create them and then concatenate them.

Comment: @JeffUK great thank you. The second one is what I need.

Comment: @KaushalSharma I think the best one the second part of what JeffUK has written.

Comment: @Christina You are welcome. Yes indeed, it is pythonic. But just to mention that Numpy arrays are much faster than python list, you might want to read about it if you need them for large scale applications.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385602/why-are-numpy-arrays-so-fast

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list with zeros and ones and shuffle it inplace. You can use something like this

```
import numpy as np

p = 2
n  = 10
labels = (np.append(np.zeros(int(n/p)),np.ones(int(n/p))))
np.random.shuffle(labels)
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code only works for p=2. Thanks anyway